# Swift - Append Data To Custom Dictionary<Int, T>

Tags: ios, swift

I use a library Swift have defined a Dictionary

```
var data = [Int: [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, [String]?, String?)]]()

var timelineObject = [(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, [String]?, String?)]()

for (index, transaction) in days.enumerated() {
    //this line working
    data = [0: timelineObject, 1: timelineObject, 2: timelineObject, 3: timelineObject]

    //this line not working
    data = [index: timelineObject]
}
```

=> How I can add data to the dictionary in for loop?

Comment: data[index] = timelineObject

Comment: I strongly recommend you to create a custom struct for `(TimelinePoint, UIColor, String, String, String?, [String]?, String?)`. You are abusing tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [index: timelineObject] // wrong
```

replace it with

```
data[index] = timelineObject // right
```

I would suggest you to read how to work with dictionaries : [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary)

Comment: @changtraisitinh please accept the answer if it helped. And do suggest PGDev's answer. That's the best way,

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using such large `tuples`, you must create a `struct/class` and use that.

Then use **`subscript`** to add values to the `Dictionary`.

**Example:**

```
struct Model {
    let point: TimelinePoint
    let color: UIColor
    //add other properties..
}

var data = [Int: [Model]]()
data[0] = Model(point:..., color: .red)
data[1] = Model(point:..., color: .black)
```